# Accessing Python slots based object members in C

Tags: python, python-c-api, slots

I have a Python class based on slots to save space

```
class my_class(object):

    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I need to access objects of this class from a C function.
When I print

```c
obj->ob_type->tp_name
```

from C, I see `my_class` but can't find a way of accessing the member values on the instance.

Comment: What kind of access are you looking for? Do you need to know the names of the slots (introspection) or do you know that there are `x` and `y` attributes and just need to access them?

Comment: I know their names. Just need to access the values.

Comment: I was able to access them just now using PyObject_GetAttrString(obj, "x"). Is that the preferred method or is there a faster way?

Comment: That's the preferred method. They are just attributes, really, implemented as descriptors on the class, accessing the value in the instance memory space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each name in `__slots__`, Python generates a descriptor object on the class (stored in the [`PyTypeObject.tp_members` struct](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_members)). Each descriptor stores an offset, just like the [`__dict__` attribute is stored as an offset](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dictoffset).

If you already know the names of the slots and just want to access the values on each instance for those, just use the normal [`PyObject_GetAttrString()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttrString) to leave it to the C-API to access the slots for you.